# Kaggle Titanic project output issue (i apologize ahead of time for newbie question)

Tags: python, kaggle

**After downloading the necessary csv files, I ran this code and received no output:**

```
    import numpy as np # linear algebra
    import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)


    import os
    for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
    for filename in filenames:
    print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
```

**Also, I received a FileNotFoundError after running the second line of code:**

```
    train_data = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/titanic/train.csv")
    train_data.head()
```

**I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed further.**

Comment: Wrong indentation for the print statement in the for loop.

Comment: Got it.  I reran and it worked.  I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run them on kaggle. The files are stored on kaggle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).